# How to redirect http request to a different URL with nginx?

Tags: http, redirect, proxy, nginx, forward

I need to redirect following URL:

http://www.example.com/product/product-name/1234

to

http://www.example.com/details/product.jsp?pid=1234

Can somebody help me on this? We are using nginx 1.1.19. Also, we need a server side redirect (URL in client side's browser should stay as the first one), not an http forward.

Thanks.